# Iterate Cucumber Scenarios Multiple Times

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, gherkin

I have to run cucumber scenarios multiple time by selecting different browser widths for a responsive design testing.
I tried 2 approaches already in my maven project. 
One is to call my cucumber-jvm file from a java file multiple time by setting the browser width. 
Second one is to call cucumber from another cucumber where I gave the browser width in a gherkin table.

1st method, I am ending up by putting the production code in maven test folder to call the cucumber test file and it is not a good idea.
2nd Method, since I am calling a large scenario file each time, my first driving gherkin is stopping after executing first row of gherkin table.

I am wondering is there any other logic to recommend for my cucumber-jvm maven project.